# Most efficient way to drive a low power LED at half brightness

Tags: led, voltage, resistors, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter

I'm working on a small project where efficiency is very important (every mA counts). I need to drive two red 3528 LED's in series and only have a 9V DC source. I want the LED's to be only around half the brightness than what they would be if I drive them with the voltage/current that's in the spec sheet. If I take an adjustable switched DC converter and turn this up to the point where I like the brightness, would I still need a resistor? And would this be the most efficient way to do it? I was surprised to see that if I hook up the DC converter it already uses up 4mA even without load. That's already the same current as what the 2 LED's alone will be using. Just wondering if a 5V voltage regulator + resistor would use more current.

Comment: Larger current limiting resistor in series with the 2 LEDs and +9V source would reduce the current.  Is there a reason why this simple approach wouldn't do?

Comment: Yes, efficiency. It sure is the most common way to do it but it's also the most inefficient way. Like I said, every mA counts in this case.

Comment: 9V is possibly a bad choice in general. The voltage is too high for a load which is only about 4-6V Max. Do you know the forward voltage drop of these LEDs when they turn on? You could probably very closely match the voltage, leaving about 1V above, and use a constant-current sink.

Comment: what I mean is, 4 x AA batteries will give you 4.8V->6V max at 2,200mAh capacity. That's way better than 9V at 600mAh or whatever the 9V batteries have. the total energy is far better, and with better voltage matching you will not be wasting 30% energy across a resistor, so efficiency in general improves.

Comment: If you only have 9v available, and need to drop it to 5v, you need a better buck regulator.  The [MAX5035](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX5035.pdf) has a maximum quiescent drain of 440 µA.

Comment: @KyranF The project is adding 2 LED's to an existing device so I'm stuck with the supply voltage. 9V is indeed far from ideal but I have no choice.

Comment: @tcrosley Thanks, the specs for the 5035 look great!

Answer (score 1):

> If I take an adjustable switched DC converter and turn this up to the point where I like the brightness, would I still need a resistor?

If you are talking about a fixed voltage converter, this will work until the temperature of the LEDs change. For example, because the LEDs are turned on and heating themselves up. As the temperature changes, the required forward voltage for a given current (and light output) changes. So this is generally a bad idea.

It is also possible to get (or design) a fixed current converter. This should work fine, but I'm not aware of any available off the shelf for 2 mA ouput.

Another option to consider is to run the LEDs at a higher current, but flash them at a low duty cycle and too fast for the eye to see.

Comment: Thanks for the information. However, I don't have the knowledge to design something myself and space is also an issue (has to be SMD). So a 5V regulator plus resistor would be the most simple way to go?

Comment: Here's an example of a step-down LED driver: [link](http://archive.siliconchip.com.au/cms/A_105436/article.html). The components could be scaled down a lot for your low current circuit, but you'd still need roughly that number of components. Seems like a lot to add to save a couple of mA.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. Perhaps I'm too focused on saving a few mA. 9V batteries ain't that expensive :)

Answer (score 1):

The MAX5035 is a good chip, and was a good idea... on the right track, that is.  But, to use an efficient voltage regulator, and then use a resistor to limit the current to the LED would work, but you would still lose some significant efficiency.  It would be more efficient to use a power management chip specifically made to drive an LED at constant current, so no power-wasteful current-limiting resistor is needed, just perhaps a much smaller current-sense resistor, and some don't even need that.  An example would be this Constant Current Buck LED Driver [HV9918K7-G](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/microchip-technology/HV9918K7-G/HV9918K7-GCT-ND/9643654) for a dollar -- I would program it for 10mA and then "dim" it to 10% of that for an effective 1mA.  But...

Every SMPS has its overhead (as you've observed), and there are synchronous chips, but they can also be pricey, and run at high frequencies and so might be hard to lay out, or still have too much overhead. So...

If you have the freedom to choose your LED(s), why not choose one with a higher forward voltage so that it will use a greater percentage of that 9 Volts.

These, from OSRAM, run at 6.25 volts forward-voltage: (OSRAM # [GR PSLR31.13-GTHP-R1R2-1](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/osram-opto-semiconductors-inc/GR-PSLR31.13-GTHP-R1R2-1/475-3227-1-ND/6569597) at Digi-Key) and cost 74 cents for one. But can we do better?

On a hunch, I thought that there might be a "perfect" LED for you to use, and I think this one might work nicely.  The CREE ML-E, (part # [MLESRD-A1-0000-000W01](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/cree-inc/MLESRD-A1-0000-000W01/MLESRD-A1-0000-000W01CT-ND/5844202) at 89 cents for 1 from Digi-Key), seems to be a nice fit at about 9.6 volts for 38mA. Here is the voltage-versus-current chart:

[image: Volts versus Current graph for Red Cree M.L.E. LED Part number MLESRD-A1-0000-000W01 LED Lighting Color XLamp ML-E Red 625nm 4-SMD, J-Lead Exposed Pad]

Although the curve may not go down as far as we might like, it does cover 9 volts, and should work for your application.  Add a resistor (I would put a 1K or 10K pot in temporarily to find out what looks visually pleasing for the voltage range you expect), and you're all set.

Also, because the LED uses a significant part of the voltage range of the 9 volts, if you calculate the efficiency, it should actually be pretty good!

So, let's actually rough it out.  I did some graphical interpolation, which I'll show you here (I extended the red-curve to the left, then kept bisecting the current until I was able to measure 2mA, about):

[image: Picture showing use of a Bezier curve to extend the graph and then extension of the grid as well to guesstimate the voltage where 2 milliamps flows in the LED per the V-versus-i curve.]

Per my guesstimate, 2 milliamps flows in this particular LED at 7 volts.  So 9-7 = 2 volts to drop across the resistor. V=IR, R=V/I=2V/2mA=1K ohms. And it's 7V/9V=78% efficient, and more so as battery voltage drops. Really not too bad for both simple AND easy.

(I know this post is 3 years old, but with >500 views, this is sure to help someone.)